# How to create pdfformfields using iTextSharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

I am using iTextSharp and CSharp for creating the pdf. I need to add formfields like checkbox, radiobutton and dropdown which can not be edited.

I used this..

```
FileStream pdffile = new FileStream(path + "/Pdf/tes.pdf",FileMode.Create);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, pdffile);
doc.Open(); 
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(100, 100, 100, 100);
RadioCheckField checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, "bhjabsdf", "on");
checkbox.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field = checkbox.CheckField;
writer.AddAnnotation(field);
doc.Close();
```

But it's not working. I also read about `PdfStamper`. But I am creating a new pdf, not changing the existing one.So I don't know whether I can use `PdfStamper`?

Thanks..

Edit:

```
private void CreateRadioButton(PdfWriter writer, PdfContentByte cb,Font font)
    {
        Rectangle rect;
        PdfFormField field;
        PdfFormField radiogroup = PdfFormField.CreateRadioButton(writer, true);
        radiogroup.FieldName = "language";
        RadioCheckField radio;
        int x = 20;
        for (int i = 0; i < Petrol.Length; i++)
        {
            rect = new Rectangle(440 + i * x, 692, 450 + i * x, 682);
            radio = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, null, LANGUAGES[i]);
            radio.BorderColor = GrayColor.GRAYBLACK;
            radio.BackgroundColor = BaseColor.WHITE;
            radio.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CIRCLE; 

            if (Petrol[i] == "F")
                radio.Checked = true;
            field = radio.RadioField;
            //Here i am setting readonly..

            field.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY);
            radiogroup.AddKid(field);                
            ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(cb, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
              new Phrase(Petrol[i], font), 451 + i * x, 684, 0);
            if (i >= 1) x = 25;
        }
        writer.AddAnnotation(radiogroup);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're creating a field 'the hard way'. There's a class named `RadioCheckField` that makes it much easier for you to create a field.

Please take a look at the book examples from [Chapter 8](http://itextpdf.com/book/chapter.php?id=8). You can find C# versions of the examples [here](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx), for instance an example named [Buttons](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=Buttons).

```
checkbox = new RadioCheckField(writer, rect, LANGUAGES[i], "on");
checkbox.CheckType = RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
PdfFormField field = checkbox.CheckField;
```

Comment: sorry..thanks it works..i was having problem because of the position.

Comment: I think that would be done like this: field.setFieldFlags(PdfFormField.READ_ONLY);

Comment: Please explain what exactly did not work. Finding the right name for the constant wasn't the problem, was it?

Comment: what does LANGUAGES[i] -- mean here. I am getting here LANGUAGES[i], does not come in current context.

Answer (score 3):

You can create your custom form template using LiveCycle and then data bind the form fields using iTextSharp like this

```
string randomFileName = Helpers.GetRandomFileName();
string formTemplate = Server.MapPath("~/FormTemplate.pdf");
 string formOutput = Server.MapPath(string.Format("~/downloads/Forms/Form-{0}.pdf",    randomFileName));

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(formTemplate);
PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new System.IO.FileStream(formOutput,   System.IO.FileMode.Create));
AcroFields fields = stamper.AcroFields;

// set form fields
fields.SetField("Date", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString());
fields.SetField("FirstName", user.FirstName);
fields.SetField("LastName", user.LastName);
fields.SetField("Address1", user.Address1);
fields.SetField("Address2", user.Address2);
fields.SetField("City", user.City);
fields.SetField("State", user.State);
fields.SetField("Zip", user.Zip);
fields.SetField("Email", user.Email);
fields.SetField("Phone", user.Phone);

// set document info
System.Collections.Hashtable info = new System.Collections.Hashtable();
info["Title"] = "User Information Form";
info["Author"] = "My Client";
info["Creator"] = "My Company";
stamper.MoreInfo = info;

 // flatten form fields and close document
stamper.FormFlattening = true;
stamper.Close();
```

Comment: thanks..But i donot have any exsisting pdf to read as u doing by formtemplate.I am creating a new pdf.help me ..if i understood wrongly..

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use a PdfStamper to create AcroForm form fields in a PDF, PdfWriter also allows you to.

Unfortunately you neither said in which way your code didn't work nor what exact requirements you have; still some sample code might bring you on track:

Have a look at chapter 8 of iText in Action, 2nd edition; especially the sample [Buttons](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=Buttons) will give you numerous hints on how to create radio buttons and check boxes. The sample [ChoiceFields](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter08&ex=ChoiceFields) will show you how to create list and combo boxes.

Comment: As Bruno hinted, you can use field.SetFieldFlags(PdfFormField.FF_READ_ONLY); be aware, though, that that can easily be undone. As Bruno puts it in the afore mentioned chapter 8 of his book: "Note that it's possible to remove the read-only flag with iText, Acrobat, or another tool. You can even remove it using a JavaScript action executed in the PDF viewer."