# how to hide a Check box in the pdfpcell while checking a condition using ItextSharp in a c#asp.net web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, itext

Context: created a checkox and tried to add the check box to the pdfpcell using the cellEvent. added the table contains the check box to parent table pdfpcell using addElement method. how do i make the checkbox.checked=true using itextsharp on satisfying certain condition like we can do in asp.net on checkbox control

```
PdfPTable fslchkbox = new PdfPTable(1);
       chkbox = new PdfPCell();
       chkbox.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT;
       iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents fslevents = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.events.FieldPositioningEvents(writer, ck2);
       chkbox.CellEvent = fslevents;
       chkbox.Border = 0;
       fslchkbox.AddCell(chkbox);

       PdfPCell FSLChk = new PdfPCell();
       FSLChk.Border = 0;
       FSLChk.HorizontalAlignment = PdfPCell.ALIGN_LEFT;
       FSLChk.AddElement(fslchkbox);
       program.AddCell(FSLChk);
       document.add(program);
```

Comment: How are you creating the CheckBox. This way? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13246888/231316

Comment: PdfContentByte cb = writer.DirectContent;
        RadioCheckField chk = new RadioCheckField(writer, new Rectangle(5,5, 1,1), "eslchk", "p1");
        chk.CheckType=RadioCheckField.TYPE_CHECK;
      chk.Checked=true;
        chk.BorderWidth=BaseField.BORDER_WIDTH_THIN;
        chk.BorderColor = BaseColor.BLACK;
        chk.BackgroundColor= BaseColor.WHITE; 
       chk.Options = RadioCheckField.READ_ONLY;
       PdfFormField ck = chk.CheckField;
      writer.AddAnnotation(ck);

Comment: the above code is the way I created the Checkbox in the pdf document