# Need to show radio button using html code only but not using PdfFormField in ITextSharp

Tags: asp.net, .net, pdf, itext, itext7

I have tried the following below code to add Radio button:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(); 
sb.Append("<input type='radio' name='gynecologicalproblem' value='Yes'> <font face='Calibri' size='1'> " + "Yes" + "  </font> </input>");
sb.Append("<input type='radio' name='gynecologicalproblem' value='No'> <font face='Calibri' size='1'> " + "No" + "  </font> </input>");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(sb.ToString());
Document pdfDoc = new Document(PageSize.A4, 10f, 10f, 10f, 0f);
HTMLWorker htmlparser = new HTMLWorker(pdfDoc);
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(pdfDoc, fs);
pdfDoc.Open();
htmlparser.Parse(sr);
pdfDoc.Close();
writer.Close();
fs.Close();
```

Comment: Is it pdf form are you trying to generate with active radio buttons? Possible duplicate of [How to create pdfformfields using iTextSharp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13245208/how-to-create-pdfformfields-using-itextsharp)

Comment: It is PDF form need to generate using only html code which is menstioned in the above code could you help me out

Comment: You use the `HTMLWorker` which meanwhile has been deprecated (and not only it but also its replacement)! Please switch to current technologies. If they similarly need improvement, you may get help.

Comment: but, i am not able to use another approach i need to use this approach only could have any solution @mkl ?

Comment: That is very unfortunate because the `HTMLWorker` supports only a very small set of html elements. Are you not able to *use another approach* because you use an itext 4.x? Later itext version at least also contain the `XMLWorker`...

Comment: Can  you Provide the sample or workable example @-mkl

Comment: Just leaving a note here that you will not get help from iText Software if you use an iText 4.x. Please upgrade to at least iText 5.5.13 (or 7.1.4, but that's a bit more work) and if you still have issues, ask again.

Comment: I am using IText 5.5.13.0 but not able to display the radio button using above code.

Comment: As mentioned above, the `HTMLWorker` supports only a very small set of html elements and meanwhile has been deprecated. As you have updated to iText 5.5.x, you can use the newer `XMLWorker` instead.

Comment: Ya I did that it's not working then I had a image to show my radio buttons